# mobile version extra skinny, viewport set, no overlapping items

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mobile

I'm using Jetpack's Mobile plugin to create a mobile version of my client's otherwise non-responsive theme. It works fine on most of the site, except this one landing page, where it loads very skinny. I don't see anything obvious that is loading at a width that would bump everything to the left.

Viewport is set like this (the Jetpack default)

```
meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"
```

The page in question is flaxandtwine.com/knitting-without-needles What am I missing? I'm happy to paste any css/html that seems relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. There was a min-width set on a ul, which fixed the view when removed.

(Don't know why those things are invisible until just *after* you post a question, and then they jump out at you.)